# How to limit the number of touches in touchesBegan in swift Spritekit

Tags: xcode, swift, touchesbegan

I have written a location finder for touch points in my touchesBegan function, I want to limit the number of touch points allowed in the view controller to 2 but I don't quite know how to do that. A little help would be fantastic.

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)


    Object.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    Object2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    Object3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true


    if Object.containsPoint(location) {
  Object.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    Object.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 135))

}

        if Object2.containsPoint(location) {
           Object2.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            Object2.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 135))
 }


        if Object3.containsPoint(location) {
            Object3.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            Object3.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 135))



    }

    }


        }
```

Comment: Clarification: I don't want the users to be able to place more than two fingers on the screen at the same time.

Comment: This is very similar to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013264/limit-touches-recognized-on-uiscrollview

Comment: That question is in Objective C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see `touches` is a `Set` struct object, and it has a cardinality, in this case `touches.count` So the point is to find this cardinality, compare it to `2` and perform action only if it is less than or equal to `2`.

So it goes like this

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if touches.count <= 2 {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Xcoder555 Please upvote or mark as answer if you find it helpful